# Deleted Module's folder before disabling it

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

**What I did**

Let's say my module was called "some_module". Without disabling from the Modules menu, I renamed that folder and changed the contents, now it's "another_module". I perceive that the site is slowing down, trying to still look for "some_module".

**What I've tried and expected**

I've tried clearing the cache a few times, expecting Drupal to rebuild it's module list based on what's available. However, I'm not sure how the inner-workings of enabling/disabling modules works, and I don't know if my site is still going slow because of this reason, or for another reason.

**What I found in the documentation**

I read some of the [documentation on Drupal Modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112), but it looks like there are some pretty simple functions like module_exists(), but it doesn't describe whether or not it will ever stop looking for "some_module".

**My question**

So, my question is: have I left behind bloated garbage that is slowing down my Drupal site by not disabling the module before renaming it?

And a bonus question...are any of [these documented benchmarks](http://drupal.org/node/79237) applicable to this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal will keep on looking for that module while there's still an entry for it in the `system` table. Delete the entry from there, delete any tables that your module created, then clear your caches. It will be as if the module never existed so if you still perceive your site to be slow at that point you know that the old module meta data was not the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I removed the row, and I think that I immediately noticed changes! I'm not crossing out placebo, but I think I feel a big difference.

Comment: Scratch that - HUGE difference. This was definitely the problem. :)

Comment: Some modules also append columns to other tables like the node table or the users table, so you should uninstall the module rather than editing the database yourself.

Comment: @Joshua no module should be adding columns to a core entity table, that's what the field system is for. Any module that does is doing things wrong, and I would say shouldn't be installed in the first place. Out of interest, which modules are you talking about?

Comment: Hey @Clive, I came across a few such modules though I can't remember all of them right now; one is https://drupal.org/project/quickstats. Also I wasn't specifically speaking about core tables; A contrib module like say commerce or ubercart (which have many support modules) can have support modules that append to their tables, and so on...

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon Yes you're absolutely right, if it's possible to uninstall a module properly you definitely should

Comment: This saved my day, after pulling my hair for hours, having tried all kinds of things from clearing cache in Drupal to Drush and Registry Rebuild!